# Cross Domain sessions and web sockets

Tags: html, security, websocket

I am working on a site that will be using HTML5 sockets to communicate with other server. At that time our users will be logged in , I can't code on other server . I am using PHP at server side. I don't know whether other server has even PHP or not. Client says PKI is a solution. So if user login on our server then I start their communication with HTML5 sockets towards other server to send and receive data. So how can other server authenticate them? I also think that I can have a userkey (like 32hash format) that is sent with HTML5 socket while communication that other server validate and then start working with that user. So client says that hacker can see data over network so I think SSL can work for it. What you guys suggest in such scenario? Please advise

More details:

There will be connection made between our users and another server using apache thrift(will be using TCP), and scenario is that user will login to our site, then we will connect them via HTML5socket to apache thrift on different domain, so in HTML5socket communication we will be forwarding userid to tell thrift server that which user is this, so it is fine. But there are two problems,

1. As HTML5sockets are at client side then a hacker can create his/her own socket and connect to that server in same way and use some one's id as these are just simple integers.
2. If we will append some thing in data then a hacker sitting on the network can get it like some hackers do this for session hijacking.

So that's why I am not sure that whether using a sort of SSL or TLS will solve the problem or some PKI or some other digital certificate. So that's why I am asking that here.

thanks

Comment: A PKI is not real a solution, its not just complete overkill,  its simply not the right tool for the job.  The real problem is that you haven't given enough information to answer this question.  Who is authenticating the client? Why?  Do you know what a cross domain proxy is?

Comment: @Rook  Ok I have added more detail so can you now please tell some thing better with this?

Answer (score 3):

SSL cannot solve this problem.   SSL is about creating a secure link between the client and server, it does **absolutely nothing** to protect the server from a malicious client.  SSL cannot solve the problem of SQL Injection or in your case [Insecure Direct Object Reference](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A4-Insecure_Direct_Object_References) relating to the user id.  Judging by this SSL suggestion you probably have never heard of [TamperData](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tamper-data/),  which allows you to read/intercept and modify all HTTPS traffic generated by your browser (Including components like flash and JavaScript),  BURP is more advanced but does the same thing.

The right way to do this is to have a shared session store that your collection of servers can access.  The client is issued a very large random number or [cryptographic nonce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce) that it uses as a verification token,  which is kind of like a session id.   This verification token is used to look up session state in the data store.  The communal session store could be as simple as a PHP page that accepts the verification token as a parameter and tells you if its linked to a valid session.

Having 3rd parties issue a callback to verify the session is really the **"right way"** to do this.  It is possible to do this with cryptography,  although it is a misuse of cryptography because it introduces the possibility of an attack,  where as a callback is absolute.  The PHP server can issue the JavaScript client an [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC) token consisting of the user id, a timestamp and the message authentication code.  The tricky part is that both the PHP server and any 3rd party will have to share a secret in order to verify the message authentication code.  If done properly you can transmit the client can transmit the token,  and 3rd parties can verify that the session hasn't expired based on the timestamp and that your servers issued the token (instead of a hacker's forgery) based on the message authentication code.